# Placing images partially off screen and rotate it

Tags: flutter

I'm currently playing around with Flutter and came across an issue where I need your help. I already googled a lot, but missing terms or there is none...

I have a wheel that can be rotated around the center of the wheel (actually of the Container) using a GestureDetector. This is fine so far and works great.
However, I'd like to place the wheel on the left, so that half of it is off screen.

What I have   ---------------+---    What I want to achieve

[image: Current Status] [image: What I want to achieve]

The wheel should still be spinnable around its center, so that the covered colors will be revealed again.

Your help is highly appreciated!

The code I use so far is basically taken from here: [How to use GestureDetector to rotate images in Flutter smoothly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61348181/how-to-use-gesturedetector-to-rotate-images-in-flutter-smoothly)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Wheel',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.yellow,
      ),
      home: const Wheel(),
    );
  }
}

class Wheel extends StatefulWidget {
  const Wheel({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _WheelState createState() => _WheelState();
}

class _WheelState extends State<Wheel> {
  double finalAngle = 0.0;
  double oldAngle = 0.0;
  double upsetAngle = 0.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _defaultApp(context);
  }

  _defaultApp(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  width: 340,
                  height: 500,
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  child: LayoutBuilder(
                    builder: (context, constraints) {
                      Offset centerOfGestureDetector = Offset(
                          constraints.maxWidth / 2, constraints.maxHeight / 2);
                      return GestureDetector(
                        behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
                        onPanStart: (details) {
                          final touchPositionFromCenter =
                              details.localPosition - centerOfGestureDetector;
                          upsetAngle =
                              oldAngle - touchPositionFromCenter.direction;
                        },
                        onPanEnd: (details) {
                          setState(
                            () {
                              oldAngle = finalAngle;
                            },
                          );
                        },
                        onPanUpdate: (details) {
                          final touchPositionFromCenter =
                              details.localPosition - centerOfGestureDetector;

                          setState(
                            () {
                              finalAngle = touchPositionFromCenter.direction +
                                  upsetAngle;
                            },
                          );
                        },
                        child: Transform.rotate(
                          angle: finalAngle,
                          child: Image.asset('assets/images/wheel.png',
                              scale: 1.0),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution. although it is not the best solution but it is workable:
If you like it or use it kindly upvote :)

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  appBar: new AppBar(
    title: new Text('Hello'),
  ),
  body: ListView(
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    reverse: true,
    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    children: [
      Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 2,
        height: 500,
        color: Colors.grey,
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (context, constraints) {
            Offset centerOfGestureDetector =
                Offset(constraints.maxWidth / 2, constraints.maxHeight / 2);
            return GestureDetector(
              behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
              onPanStart: (details) {
                final touchPositionFromCenter =
                    details.localPosition - centerOfGestureDetector;
                upsetAngle = oldAngle - touchPositionFromCenter.direction;
              },
              onPanEnd: (details) {
                setState(
                  () {
                    oldAngle = finalAngle;
                  },
                );
              },
              onPanUpdate: (details) {
                final touchPositionFromCenter =
                    details.localPosition - centerOfGestureDetector;
                setState(
                  () {
                    finalAngle =
                        touchPositionFromCenter.direction + upsetAngle;
                  },
                );
              },
              child: Transform.rotate(
                angle: finalAngle,
                child: Image.network(
                    'https://static.toiimg.com/thumb/msid-31346158,width-748,height-499,resizemode=4,imgsize-114461/.jpg',
                    scale: 1.0),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

}

Comment: Works as expected. Thank you!

Comment: Could you explain, why this works with a ListView?

Comment: Surely.. Firstly let's understand what a list view is.. A list view is kind of a combination of a singleChildScrollView and a Column so it can take as many height and width as much we describe.. so in the solution i have described 3 things: Axis.. by default scrolling is list view is top to bottom but to change it from left to right, you can use Axis.horizontal, next is reversing it so that it starts from right to left and not left to right and the main key is that the container uses double width of the screen

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I think I got it